# Derive the posterior distribution of a transformation

Tags: distributions, bayesian, posterior

If we have X1,...,Xn iid with normal distribution $(\mu, \theta)$ where $\theta$ is the variance of the normal distribution, and an improper prior of $1/\theta$. 
How would I derive the posterior distribution for $\frac{n^{1/2}(\mu-\overline{x})}{s}$ where $s^2=\frac{\sum(x_i-\overline{x})^2}{(n-1)}$. 
I have gotten to the point where I derive the posterior distribution without the transformation applied, but I don't know how to proceed from there.

So I have 
likelihood:

$L(\mu,\theta)=\frac{1}{(2\pi\theta)^{n/2}}e^{\frac{1}{2\theta}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\mu)^2}$
and

prior $1/\theta$.

Therefore the posterior likelihood would be 
$\frac{1}{\theta^{n+2/2}}e^{\frac{-1}{\theta} \sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\mu)^2}$.

(Getting rid of the constants)

Comment: I presume you mean that the prior on $(\mu,\theta)$ is proportional to $1/\theta$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The posterior distribution on $(\mu,\theta)$ is thus proportional to 
$$\theta^{-(n+2)/2}\exp\left\{\frac{-1}{\theta} \sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\mu)^2\right\}$$This means that the marginal posterior distribution of $\mu$ is proportional to$$\int_0^\infty\theta^{-n/2-1}\exp\left\{\frac{-1}{\theta} \sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\mu)^2\right\}\text{d}\theta\propto\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\mu)^2\right\}^{-n/2}$$since $\theta$ is then conditionally distributed as an Inverse Gamma with shape parameter $n/2$. This means that $\mu$ is marginally distributed as a Student's $t$ variate, with $n-1$ degrees of freedom:
$$\pi(\mu|\mathbf{x})\propto\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})^2+n(\bar{x}-\mu)^2\right\}^{-(n-1+1)/2}\propto\left\{s^2+\frac{n(\bar{x}-\mu)^2}{n-1}\right\}^{-(n-1+1)/2}$$
which shows the scale parameter of the Student's $t$ marginal posterior is $s^2/n$. Hence,$$\frac{\mu-\bar{x}}{s/\sqrt{n}}\sim\mathscr{T}_{n-1}$$a standard Student's $t$ distribution.